# 404 Not Found nginx/1.12.0 Push Notification

Tags: php, android, jquery, nginx, google-cloud-messaging

I'm in big trouble that I have no idea what it can be.

I have an APP that has more than 100k users on the table, I happen to call the GCM service inside LOOP after about 1 minute presents this error message.

I have treated all the fields so as not to be NULL, I do not know what it can be!

Will it be timeout from ajax?

The call in GCM is as follows:

```
$url    = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
    $fields = array(
        'data' => array(
            "mensagem" => $message
        ),
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids
    );
    if (is_array($data)) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $fields['data'][$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . apiKey,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    $ch      = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    curl_close($ch);
```

**Loop to bring the database id**-------------

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $num / 1000; $i++)
    {
    $query = $con->query("SELECT gcm_regid from registration where status ='S' and LENGTH(gcm_regid) = 152  and app_id=$Id_Aplicativo LIMIT $current_num,1000");
    foreach($query as $data)
        {
        if (!is_null($data["gcm_regid"]))
            {
            $row[] = is_null($data["gcm_regid"]) ? " " : $data["gcm_regid"];
            $cont = $cont + 1;
            }
        }

    // print_r($row);

    $pushStatus = send_notification($con, $row, $mensagem, array(
        'titulo' => is_null($titulo) ? " " : $titulo, //$titulo,
        'sub_mensagem' => is_null($sub_mensagem) ? " " : $sub_mensagem, //$sub_mensagem,
        'content_mensagem' => is_null($content_mensagem) ? " " : $content_mensagem, //$content_mensagem,
        'content_info' => is_null($content_info) ? " " : $content_info, //$content_info,
        'url_imagem' => is_null($path . $nome_imagem) ? " " : $path . $nome_imagem, //$path.$nome_imagem,// Esse Path vem do arquivo Conect.php
        'url_audio' => is_null($path_audio . $filenameAudio) ? " " : $path_audio . $filenameAudio, //$path_audio.$filenameAudio, // Esse Path vem do arquivo Conect.php
        'tipo_notificacao' => is_null($TipoNotificacao) ? " " : $TipoNotificacao, //$TipoNotificacao
    ));
    $row = null;
    $current_num+= 1000;
    }
```

404 Not Found Nginx/1.12.0

[image]

Comment: How many calls are successful?

Comment: I'm not sure because it gives the error message 404 not found, but it keeps calling the GCM service.
So I do not know if it's jquery timeout, whether it's GCM service error or something else

Comment: You should not call it over AJAX because this request is going to take a lot of time. So you should schedule it in background. Also make sure you debug just the php script  and see if your curl is erroring out and if so why. You can add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);` to get detailed logs of what is happening in background

Comment: But I need to call via ajax because the system is already ready, already has several users using it.
Is there not a way to increase time?

Comment: You can use `set_time_limit(0)` at the top of your PHP script to set the timeout to 0. For Ajax call you need to specify the timeout parameter `timeout` and give it number of seconds you want to wait for the call

Comment: Tarun,I timed here and gave 3 minutes and 5 seconds then it displays the Ngnix 404 message.

Comment: hard to comment more, this requires debugging or professional help

Comment: I put timeout 0 in the php pages and in ajax I put, timeout: 500000, but to no avail   :'(
Worse than this mistake the users, they think it made the error of sending.